# Server Redirect With Ports?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, port

I don't have much experience with Apache or servers, so my apologies if this is a stupid question. I am trying to redirect `http://example.com:5557` to `http://203.0.113.111:5557`. Is this something I can do in the .htaccess file and, if so, what would that look like?

Here is my idea:

```
Redirect 301 "http://example.com:5557" "http://203.0.113.111:5557"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this in `.htaccess`, but not with the mod_alias `Redirect` directive. The `Redirect` directive matches against the URL-path only. You need to match against the HTTP *Host* request header, which contains the hostname + port number.

Try the following using mod_rewrite instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com:5557$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://203.0.113.111:5557/ [R=301,L]
```

Note that this redirects the document root (homepage) only, as stated in your example. If you need to redirect any URL to the same URL at the target domain  then use the following `RewriteRule` instead:

```
:
RewriteRule ^ http://203.0.113.111:5557%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

NB: Test first with 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.